# Trying to find a short story where a dragon is impersonating a wizard

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dragons, wizards

I just remembered a memory of a short story I read back in middle school.

From what I remember, the story starts off with the 'wizard' blowing smoke into the sky as he looks down on the local village from his home atop the nearby hill (or mountain?).

Then a local villager begins to discuss rumors of the wizard owning a guard animal of sorts, and that he saw smoke and fire from the crack below the wizard's door.

Then a villager goes to sneak into the cottage atop the hill to see what the animal is, and then it's revealed that the wizard is actually a dragon, who then eats the intruder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like *[The Rule of Names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rule_of_Names)* by Ursula K. Le Guin, first published in [the April 1964 issue](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58201) of *Fantastic Stories of Imagination*.

> The story is set on Sattins Island, a small rural island among the Islands of Earthsea, and opens with the schoolteacher, Palani, introducing the concept of naming to her pupils: people have one name as children, then are given their adult name at puberty, but this name must be kept private as it can be used by magicians to cast spells on the person. Sattinsmen are very superstitious. They believe that to wish a neighbor "good morning" will change the weather for the worse; that dragons are fond of eating maidens; that two wizards in one town are trouble. **Their resident magician is a fat, incompetent man nicknamed "Underhill" because he lives in a cave outside the village**.
>
> **One day, a stranger from the archipelago arrives on the island. The locals dub him Blackbeard. He hires a village lad called Birt to guide him to Underhill's home**. Once there, Blackbeard reveals that he is a mage, searching for the treasure of his ancestors, which was stolen by a dragon. He believes Underhill to be a wizard who defeated the dragon and made off with the treasure.
>
> **The two enchanters engage in a shapechanging battle, ending with Underhill in dragon's form. Blackbeard uses his secret weapon by using Underhill's true name, Yevaud, in a spell which will lock him into his true form. This proves effective, but not as Blackbeard expected; Underhill proves to be the dragon who stole the treasure of Pendor, and so his true form is the dragon. Yevaud devours Blackbeard**. Birt flees the island, taking his love Palani with him. With his true identity revealed, and with his predatory dragon nature reinforced by being called by his true name, Yevaud wreaks havoc on Sattins.

Comment: It's really more of a dragon impersonating a *hobbit*.